# Migrating Questions Best Suited for other forums

Tags: discussion, feature-request

In other forums, there seems to be an option to ask for question to be migrated in to more appropriate forum but I can't to find it here. Am I missing a trick or does SFSE not have this?

Answer (score 6):

It's under closing / off topic /other site in the network.

[image]

I believe this is available as of 3k rep, when granted the [Cast Close And Reopen Votes Privilidge](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions)

Comment: I do not see that option. All I see is the salesforce.meta option

Comment: Interesting, I was in the understanding/belief everyone who could vote on close question had access: https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions

Comment: I also have never seen that second option.

Comment: @AdrianLarson - Any idea why most of us do not see this option? I would assume by design, but what is the criteria to be able to see it